# select data from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables A and B

```
      A                             B

id  name  age               id     registered
--- ----- ----              ---    -----------
1   abc   19                 2         yes     
2   xyz   20
3   qwe   34
4   asdf  43
```

I want to select all the fields from table A that have registered. I.e. select the data `2 xyz 20  yes`.

How do I do it using mysql?

Comment: Did you try to use JOIN clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want all of table A and values from B I think you're looking for:

```
select * from TableA left join TableB on TableA.ID=TableB.ID
```

If you want those that just have records in Table B Use:

```
select * from TableA inner join TableB on TableA.ID=TableB.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a JOIN:

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, A.age
FROM
  A INNER JOIN B
  ON A.id = B.id
WHERE
  B.registered='yes'
```

or a IN clause:

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, A.age
FROM A
WHERE
  A.id IN (SELECT id FROM b WHERE registered='yes')
```